# Blackberry installation problem: users miss OK dialogs and the app ends up not being installed

Tags: blackberry

We have a Blackberry app that is installed by users OTA.  The install works fine *as long as* the user clicks OK on all of the dialog boxes that come up during the process.

However, if something else happens during installation (like a phone call or whatever), the user ends up never clicking the dialogs, so the app is never completely installed successfully.

Is there any way to force an installation process to re-show the dialogs if the user wanders away?  Alternatively (or additionally), is there any way for an app to be aware that one or more components have not been installed successfully?  Right now the app starts up but then spins forever, if everything has not been installed correctly.

Sorry if a lot of this doesn't make sense - I'm not a Blackberry developer, but I've been charged with investigating this problem generally.

Comment: So the problem is that users need to install multiple app components to get everything working?   Perhaps getting it down to a single install would avoid some of your issue.

Comment: I may have described that part incorrectly. I think it's only installing one application, but the installer is requesting various permissions for the app, some of which don't get granted by users that don't see the dialogs (for whatever reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can reproduce the problem on a device, dump the event log and take a look.  If I had to guess, I'd say that the dialogs being skipped are permission-granting dialogs or maybe even firewall dialogs.  If this is the case, you'll see various exceptions thrown by your app (i.e. ControlledAccessException).  You can work around this by catching the exception and displaying a proper message informing them that they need to take some action (i.e. allow app in the firewall settings).  If it's a case of needing additional application permissions, you can use the [ApplicationPermissionsManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissionsManager.html) class to see what permissions your app has been granted, and to ask for additional permissions if required.

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm going to see if I can get the event log. If it is all permission-granting dialogs, then it should be possible to modify the source code to catch the exceptions and/or use the permission manager prophilactically.